# What is the $1$-norm of a matrix?

Tags: matrices, definition, normed-spaces, matrix-norms, nuclear-norm

Let $A \in \mathbb C^{n \times n}$ be some matrix. I'm trying to understand what $\lvert\!\lvert A \rvert\!\rvert_1$ means. I found two definitions:

1. $\lvert\!\lvert A \rvert\!\rvert_1$ is the Schatten norm for $p=1$, so $\lvert\!\lvert A \rvert\!\rvert_1 := \mathrm{Tr}\left(\sqrt{A^\dagger A}\right)$.
2. $\lvert\!\lvert A \rvert\!\rvert_1$ is the maximum of the absolute column sums.

Are these two definitions equivalent? If so, how does one see that?

Comment: The Holder (aka elementwise) norms yield a _third_ possibility - the Manhattan norm
$$\|A\|_1 = \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n\;|A_{ij}|$$
This norm differs from both the Schatten/Nuclear norm and the max-column-sum norm, yet confusingly they all use the same $\|A\|_1$ notation.

Answer (score 1):

No, these are two different norms as you can easily see with a randomly generated example.

If you're working with Schatten $p$-norms, please take the time to explain your notation in your writing.

If the only Schatten norm that you're using is $p=1$, then a commonly used notation is $\| A \|_{*}$.